# Proper way of updating a version number for self-developed package in Julia

Tags: package, julia

Suppose I develop a package in Julia called `my_package` and I want to update its version number. What is the proper way of doing that?

- Should I just edit the `version` field in `Project.toml` manually?
- Or, should I use the package manager for that task? What would be the proper command in that case?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just edit it manually in the file yourself.
The package manager doesn't have a function to do it for you.

Comment: Package managers need to ask themselves "have I updated the manifests?" the same way one asks "is my seatbelt on?" in old cars without a computer.